# devise's my after_sign_up is worked. But it can not load resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, frontend

I made new `after_sign_up` in my `RegistrationsController`.
And it looks work.
But it error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`.
And I can find `after_sign_up`'s `resource`is `nil`. But  in `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for`'s resource is existed. How can I get `resource` wholly to `after_sign_up`?

*registraions_controller.rb*

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :force_ssl!
  before_filter :require_update_ability, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    super # Don't fix me!
    puts 'user is created.'
  end

  def after_sign_up
    puts resource
  end

  private

  def force_ssl!  
    if Rails.env.production?
      unless request.host == 'dashboard.userhabit.io' && request.ssl?
        redirect_to :protocol => 'https', :host => 'dashboard.userhabit.io'
      end
    end
  end

  def require_update_ability
    unless can? :update, current_user
      flash[:error] = I18n.t 'messages.not_authorized'
      redirect_to apps_path
    end
  end

  protected

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    puts resource
    after_sign_up_path(resource)
  end
end
```

*config/routes.rb*

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'users/registrations', :sessions => 'users/sessions', :passwords => 'users/passwords'}
devise_scope :user do
  match 'users/after_sign_up' => 'users/registrations#after_sign_up', :as => 'after_sign_up', :via => :get
end
```

*registraions/after_sign_up.erb*

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => after_sign_up_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why. But `after sign_up` method make resource nil. And So I resource variable get into instance class variable. But instance class variable is nil too. So I solve with making global variable. However it's not clean. Anybody have better idea? And I paste my code.

```rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :force_ssl!
  before_filter :require_update_ability, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  $user

  def create
    if after_sign_up_path(resource)
      super
      $user = params[:user]
    else
      super # Don't fix me!
      puts 'else'
    end
  end

  def after_sign_up
    @user = $user
  end

  private

  def force_ssl!
    if Rails.env.production?
      unless request.host == 'dashboard.userhabit.io' && request.ssl?
        redirect_to :protocol => 'https', :host => 'dashboard.userhabit.io'
      end
    end
  end

  def require_update_ability
    unless can? :update, current_user
      flash[:error] = I18n.t 'messages.not_authorized'
      redirect_to apps_path
    end
  end

  protected

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    puts 'AfterInactiveSignUp'
    puts resource
    after_sign_up_path(resource)
  end
end
```